# Generating hyperlink from formula outcome

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I'm having a problem with hyperlinks in Excel

```
=K1&TEXT(B5,"YYYY-MM-DD")&K2&MONTH(B5)&K3&B3&K4&TEXT(B4,"YYYY-MM-DD")&K5&MONTH(B4)&K6&1&K7&20&K8&YEAR(B4)&K9&B2&K10&YEAR(B1)
```

The idea is to create an automatically generated link for report for the week we are in. The formula works, the generated address works, but I'm having a problem with converting it to a clickable link with no need to copy and paste it to a browser.

The resulting link is 351 characters so i tried to reference just the cell which contains the formula but in both cases it throws me `#VALUE!`

When tried to make the formula with `CONCATENATE` but the result is the same

Any idea how to overcome the character limit? As I suppose that's the problem.

Comment: Please add some example of the address.

Comment: The address is different from the text that displays. There's probably a solution within VBA where you can take those inputs and convert them to a link but have a simple Display text that works around this limitation.

Comment: https://eu-icqa-repo.corp.amazon.com/metric/metric_daily_view/location?assist=threshold&date=2021-07-31&date_range=daily&fc=KTW1&fc_filter=EU&metric=Safety%2FAssociate+Satisfaction%09&month=07&quarter=3&report_id=161&search_type=location&start_date=2021-07-27&start_month=07&start_quarter=1&start_week=20&start_year=2021&view=op_area&week=30&year=2021

Comment: That's the generated address it work fine. you will not be able to access it its an internal only site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=Hyperlink(K1&TEXT(B5,"YYYY-MM-DD")&K2&MONTH(B5)&K3&B3&K4&TEXT(B4,"YYYY-MM-DD")&K5&MONTH(B4)&K6&1&K7&20&K8&YEAR(B4)&K9&B2&K10&YEAR(B1),"Click for Report")`

`=Hyperlink(https://eu-icqa-repo.corp.amazon.com/metric/metric_daily_view/location?assist=threshold&date=2021-07-31&date_range=daily&fc=KTW1&fc_filter=EU&metric=Safety%2FAssociate+Satisfaction%09&month=07&quarter=3&report_id=161&search_type=location&start_date=2021-07-27&start_month=07&start_quarter=1&start_week=20&start_year=2021&view=op_area&week=30&year=2021,"Click for Report")`

The VBA syntax would be something like:

```
Sub AddHyperlinkToCell()
Dim Link As String
Link = "https://eu-icqa-repo.corp.amazon.com/metric/metric_daily_view/location?assist=threshold&date=2021-07-31&date_range=daily&fc=KTW1&fc_filter=EU&metric=Safety%2FAssociate+Satisfaction%09&month=07&quarter=3&report_id=161&search_type=location&start_date=2021-07-27&start_month=07&start_quarter=1&start_week=20&start_year=2021&view=op_area&week=30&year=2021"

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A1"), _
Address:=Link, _
TextToDisplay:="Click Here for Report"

End Sub
```

Comment: That works partially. it overcomes the character limit. but the link is dynamically generated. an it always drives me to the report from that exact date which was pasted,

Very useful indeed but not for that use case thanks btw !

Also been digging more and found something that seems to work well still have to test few things. 
original post [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-do-i-do-a-hyperlink-that-exceeds-255-characters.539414/post-4424728)

Comment: @Killroy I'm glad you're closer to your answer, hopefully some combination of this and what you find can get your result. Where I put the link, I figure you may be able to apply the formula although I'm not 100% on the syntax there. If you do figure it out, come back and answer your own question so it's useful for others!

Comment: Sure next day at work i will check for all the new info to make it work fully and answer all i got :)

Answer (score 0):

After some research if found an old post which provided me with an answer

[Link to original post](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-do-i-do-a-hyperlink-that-exceeds-255-characters.539414/#post-4424728)

you just need to paste it in the worksheet code not a module! and in the code just change the range of cell in which you want to generate those extra long hyperlinks.

The only thing you need to do after that if you have some dynamic ranges in the formulas like i do, Just force refresh the formula. I just recorded a quick macro that re-enters the formula to into the cell with a button click. and the link changes accordingly to date range selected.

Hope its useful for someone else :)

Tested code below:

```
    '     davesexel     http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1125569-creating-in-excel-a-hyperlink-to-a-route-made-in-google-maps.html#post4311156
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Application.EnableEvents = False 'Does not appear to need this..  I thought it would as i thought the change in the sheet done in line 60 would set this code off again. This code line would have avoided that by turning off codes of this nature ***
10      Dim strDaveLongSExelHype As String 'Done at complile time to Tell VBA initially where to go when seeing strDaveLongSexelHype anywhere else in the code ( This may likely change as required to hause changing length values      http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/361246-vbnullstring.html
20      Let strDaveLongSExelHype = Target.Value 'Target is a reserved Word used for VBA for the Range Object corresponding to where you "Hit"  ( or the Range which you selected before hitting hit Enter ) The .Value Property assigned to one cell returns the value in an appropriate type, ( in our case typically a String ), of what is in the cell. In other words what you typed in is "put in" strDaveLongSExelHype
30      Dim WhereIWantToInsertMyLongThong As Range 'Variable for the Spreadsheet Area, as a Range Object, where you are expecting to Insert your Long Things.
40      Set WhereIWantToInsertMyLongThong = Range("A13:A14") ' CHANGE this to suit your wishes!  ####
'41  Set WhereIWantToInsertMyLongThong = Cells '  ##### This alternatve would result in the code working over the whole Worksheet
50      If Not Intersect(WhereIWantToInsertMyLongThong, Target) Is Nothing Then 'The VBA Intersect Method will return a Range Object that represents the intersection of two, or more, ranges. Nothing is a Special VBA Object for a "not yet assigned Object". If we Not get that then we have a Object, ( in this case a range Object ( a Cell ) ) that intercepts the entire Range where you wanted to be able to Insert your Long Thing ( That entire Range was specified in Line 40 ( or 41 ) )
'       The Hyperlink Property of a range returns ( or refers )  to a collection of  "all to do with" the Hyperlinks associated with that range Object. Amongst other things a .Add Method is available with 2 compulsory and 2 optional arguments.  Based on the arguments, a specific Hyperlink is put in the Range. Anchor:= _____ says where the Hyperlinkk is written in. Address:=_____in this case is the URL itself.  ScreenTip:=____is the bit of text in the cell which you usually put in as something like “Click Me”. But just for fun I used the whole text of your URL again.   TextToDisplay:=___Is where you put what you want to be displayed in the Box which comes up when you hover over your Hyperlink cell with the mouse. Again just for fun I used your whole URL. I guess you might want just something Like “This goes to my Google Maps Pub Crawl Route when I click on it”
60          Target.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Target, Address:="" & strDaveLongSExelHype & "", ScreenTip:="" & strDaveLongSExelHype & "", TextToDisplay:="" & strDaveLongSExelHype & "" ' " DaveSexuel's Workaround " Allowing a very long  ( greater than 255 character ) URL to be put in an Excel Cell    http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1125569-creating-in-excel-a-hyperlink-to-a-route-made-in-google-maps.html#post4311156
'70      Else 'Do Not need to do anything here...  but just for fun, lines 70 and 75 would result in  a message box poping up telling you that you selected outside the range you specified in Line 40 ( or 41 )
'75      MsgBox prompt:="Your Selected Range was not within Area " & Replace((WhereIWantToInsertMyLongThong.Address), "$", "", 1) & ""  ' Address Property applied to Range Object returns a String including the $ bits. So a simple Replace withn that String  ,    of   a  $   ,   with  a special VBA String representing a string variable not filled yet  ,   starting looking at character  1 ( first )  ,  and replace all of them ( that is what -1 means in this case )
80          End If
Application.EnableEvents = True ' I leave this in just to be on the safe side!!  **
End Sub
```